# values are being overwritten or ignored in factory function in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, controller, factory

I have a function in my factory that looks like this:

```
myApp.factory('SaveDate', ['$resource',
function saveDateFactory($resource) {
  var myData = '';

  //this grabs the data we need for the url below
  function setMyData(data) {
    myData = data;
  }

  return {
    setMyData: setMyData,
    resource: $resource(myData, {}, {
      query: { method: "POST", params: {}, isArray: false }
    })
  };
}]);
```

I call it in my controller like this:

```
vm.myFunction1 = function ($resource) {

  vm.myDate = '/api/Product/SetMilestoneDate/vm.officeKey/vm.whichMilestone/vm.yearSelected/vm.monthSelected/vm.daySelected';

  SaveDate.setMyData(vm.myDate);

  //this should save the date for milestones 
  SaveDate.resource.query();
  vm.cleanUp();

};
```

I am getting the right value into setMyData in the factory just fine. In the bottom part of the factory (in the return) it is ignoring this value and going with whatever value I used when I declared the variable in the first place. If I declare the variable with hard values that are being supplied through myData, the function works perfectly (it grabs the value from where I declared it). Does anyone have any ideas on why it would ignore the myData value from setMyData and just use the default? Thanks for your help on this!

Answer (score 0):

This might help: [Angular Factory Variables Won't Update - Instance gets old values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22337279/angular-factory-variables-wont-update-instance-gets-old-values)

> Note: All services in Angular are singletons. That means that the injector uses each recipe at most once to create the object. The injector then caches the reference for all future needs. http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers